# Specification for CUPS printing options

Tags: printing, cups

I would like to ask if someone knows where can I find all the possible printing options the can CUPS send to backend/filter etc.

These are some of the possible options:

```
com.apple.print.PrintSettings.PMBorder..b.
com.apple.print.PrintSettings.PMBorderType..n.=1
com.apple.print.PrintSettings.PMColorMatchingMode..n.=0
com.apple.print.PrintSettings.PMColorSpaceModel..n.=0
com.apple.print.PrintSettings.PMCopies..n.=1
com.apple.print.PrintSettings.PMCopyCollate..b.
```

I would like to get the full list of these options, but can't find any specification for that.

https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-2.0/api-cups.html#cupsParseOptions

Answer (score 1):

### Documentation

The standard documentation of `cupsd` configuration file is available with:

```
man cupsd.conf
```

### Modification

These options are configured through the `cupsd` configuration file which is:

```
/etc/cups/cupsd
```

If `cupsd` is running it will overwrite it. Hence so as to be able to edit it, here is how to proceed:

1. stop `cupsd`:

   ```
   cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
   /usr/bin/sudo launchctl unload org.cups.cupsd.plist
   ```
2. edit `cupsd` configuration file:

   ```
   cd /etc/cups
   cp cupsd.conf cupsd.conf.orig
   vi cupsd.conf
   ```
3. start `cupsd`:

   ```
   cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
   /usr/bin/sudo launchctl load org.cups.cupsd.plist
   ```